# WebView with touch event UITapGestureRecognizer unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This error always happen when I run my code. Could you please tell me where is the problem and how to fix it in Swift 3?

**Error:**

> [UIWebView tapAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f9bfbf14e60

**Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.  
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf")!
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))

        let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: webView, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
        webViewTapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        webViewTapped.delegate = self
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(webViewTapped)
   }

   func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       let point = sender.location(in: self.view)
       print("123")
       print(point.x)
       print(point.y)
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the target from `webView`:

```
let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: webView, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
```

To `self`:

```
let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
```

Comment: else take this from `let point = sender.location(in: self. webView)
`

Comment: it work perfectly, You just save my life. Could you please explain me more why target must be self, not webview

Comment: @user3783161 - you called the webview in the current class, so self is identify the all subview

Comment: @user3783161 `target` indicates object on which the `action` will be performed. Your WebView does not have `tapAction` selector, your  ViewController does

Comment: @mag_zbc - really appreciate my bro

Comment: @user3783161 -- target needs the UIControls, but webview is a UIView not a controller, so this is the reason, we convert our target to current class,

Answer (score 2):

replace you with your code

```
    let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Target and action are used to refer to a particular method/ action. In your case , you are creating a UITapGestureRecognizer. The UITapGestureRecognizer needs to know what action is to invoked.

A target is a receiver of an action message. A control or, more frequently, its cell holds the target of its action message as an outlet (see Outlets). The target usually is an instance of one of your custom classes, although it can be any Cocoa object whose class implements the appropriate action method.

An action is the message a control sends to the target or, from the perspective of the target, the method the target implements to respond to the action message.

As suggested by @AnbuKarthik use target as self as here self is a receiver of an action message not webview. For more information on Target-Action check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html).

```
let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
```